# Build Scope Query to Get First level of Children

Tags: sxa, sitecore-query, querybuilder

I am using `Sitecore 9.1.1` and `SXA 1.8.1`

I have an item called `Seat`, this item is a parent to many other items on multiple levels of two templates, `Topic Details` and `Topic Listing`.

[image]

In `Seat` (my parent item), I have a search results component, where I want to return `only the first level of children of Seat`.

Is there a way to achieve this using the OOTB Scope query? noting that, the children are of two different templates, not just one.

**My current scope query is this:**

```
template:{TopicDetailsID};template:{TopicListingID};+sxa:UnderCurrentPage;sxa:ExcludeCurrentPage
```

This returns all of the children on all levels, and I'm trying to get only the first level.

Comment: Can you add sample items tree to your question and explain what you want to get as a result of your query?

Comment: I attached image above...sea transportation and Jetskies_Private Water Crafts PWC based on the same template and others from another template so I need to write query to get five items under sea transportation and to use the same query to get items under Jetskies_Private Water Crafts.

Comment: so can I write query to get all item from "template 1 or template 2" and not "parent or indecent"

Comment: An option to consider is making the three levels use different templates. Then your query would only need to use the template for the items you want returned in the search results.